# OpenVPN on OpenBSD 4.8: How do I set up a VPN for road warriors in bridged mode

Tags: openvpn, openbsd, bridge

I'd like to set up an OpenVPN server on my OpenBSD router.

I'd like to run it in bridged mode, so the IPs given to the road warriors are from the local network subnet. I'd like to use the DNS server of OpenVPN for those clients.

I found some tutorials on how to do this, but most seem to be out of date, to the point that it's virtually impractical to use anything from it.

Do I have to compile it from ports, isn't installing with pkg_add sufficient?

Could someone please point me to a how-to that is somewhat up-to-date?

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty easy using openvpn.  You will need to setup your server to use a specific tap interface.  Then just use ifconfig to bridge tapX to your LAN interface.  More info on bridge here:

http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=bridge&sektion=4&arch=&apropos=0&manpath=OpenBSD+Current

As requested here is the how-to:

http://www.chrisk.de/blog/2010/03/how-to-openvpn-on-openbsd-as-layer2-vpn/